# How to import a part of index from main Solr server(based on a query) to another Solr server and then do incremental import later(the updated index)?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have a main solr server(solr1) which stores indexes of all doc, and want to implement the follow function:
1. First make a full import of my doc updated/created recently(last 1 or 2 weeks) from solr1.
2. Make delta import at intervals to copy the change of my doc from solr1 to solr2. - doc may be deleted, updated, created during this period.

-- as the function supported by SqlEntityProcessor to import data from DB to Solr.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#SolrEntityProcessor
SolrEntityProcessor can make a full-import from one Solr to another solr based on a query(using query parameter in config file), but seems can't do delta import later: no deltaImportQuery and deltaQuery configuration, which is supported in SqlEntityProcessor.

How can I implement this function?
Thanks for any help and reply :)

Comment: Thanks, I reviewed all of my posts(only 5 yet), update them and accept the answers that help solve the problem.

Comment: Nice one, thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to implement the equivalent of the deltaImportQuery by using a Solr field and filter query that can simulate this.

I would suggest the addition of a `timestamp` field to your Solr schema. Below is the field definition from the [solr example schema](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_6/solr/example/solr/conf/schema.xml?view=markup).

```
   <field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" 
       default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>
```

This will create a field that records the last time a record was added to the Solr index and you can add a filter query `fq` option to your SolrEntityProcessor query to limit the results to only those items where the timestamp field value is greater than or equal to the last time your import handler was last run using DateMath in the filter query.

Here are some good references for how DateMath works.

- [DateMathParser](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/util/DateMathParser.html)
- [Solr Date Format](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/lweug/Solr+Date+Format) (I realize you may not be using LucidWorks Solr, but the examples still apply).

Comment: Paige Cook, Thanks for your reply.
We do have a field last_modified to record the timestamp the index of a doc was created or updated.
But how can I get the last time I ran the import handler, using ${dataimporter.last_index_time} as the example in SqlEntityProcessor?

Comment: Yes - according to - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Using_delta-import_command "... Note the variable ${dataimporter.last_index_time} The DataImportHandler exposes a variable called last_index_time which is a timestamp value denoting the last time full-import 'or' delta-import was run..."

Comment: Thanks, Paige Cook, - Describe my problem more clearly: 
I have a main solr server(solr1) which stores indexes of all doc, and want to implement the follow function:
1. First make a full import of my doc updated/created recently(last 1 or 2 weeks) from solr1.
2. Make delta import at intervals to copy the change of my doc from solr1 to solr2. - doc may be deleted, updated, created during this period.

Comment: We have a field last_modified which records the timestamp an doc is created or updated.

Task1 can be easily implemented:
<entity name="sep" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" query="+from:jeffery +last_modified:[${dataimporter.request.start_time} TO NOW]" url="http://mainsolr:8080/solr/"/>

But how can implement task2 with SolrEntityProcessor? Seems SolrEntityProcessor doesn't support "command=delta-import".
How I use dataimporter.last_index_time? Totally have no clue yet.

Comment: I am trying to implement this function, after all is done, I will update this post :)